# Twilio SMS verify destination phone numbers and verification ID

Tags: sms, httprequest, httpresponse, twilio, verification

I have two questions.

I am creating a website for a client I am trying to code in Twilio SMS tools for end users and for management. I have the request and response tools built so I am all set functionally. So the questions are:

A. Can I send SMS message to any phone number OR does every number I send an SMS have to be added to twilio and verified before I can freely send SMS? It would be nice if I could just collect my phone numbers from the end users and free them from the pain of the verification process.

B. If I must verify end users then can I send SMS messages to them with their verification code? Right now an automated message call is sent to the phone number that wants SMS updates and you have to key in a six digit verification code....AND then you can send that person SMS messages. The phone call is kind of awkward.

Comment: Both of the answers below were equally helpful.  So I am not sure who wins the green check-mark :) I up-voted both....Thanks for the helpful answers.

Answer (score 4):

A.  Once you have a regular Twilio account, you can send an SMS to any phone number.  However, some phone numbers (e.g., most landlines) cannot accept an SMS.  If you try to send an SMS to those numbers with your cellphone, you will probably get a message back from the carrier that the number cannot accept SMS.  However, Twilio will report success in sending the message, even though the message obviously cannot be sent to that number, and you will get no indication that the message did not go through.

But, no, there is no need to specifically add the numbers as verified for them to work with Twilio.

You can use a service like https://www.carrierlookup.com/ (which Twilio told me about) to check if a phone number can receive SMS messages.

B. -- you do not need to verify end users through Twilio, although I do think there are restrictions on a Twilio trial account that will be removed once you have a paid Twilio account.

Comment: I do not have a regular account yet...Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Twilio evangelist here

Once you upgrade, you can send a message to any phone number.  While you are using a trial account, you have to verify a number in order to send a message to it.  More info about how a trial account works is here:

http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-does-twilios-free-trial-work

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding verification: Twilio has a service that allows verifying phone numbers, including format, carrier, if it's mobile or landline, etc: https://www.twilio.com/lookup

API Docs: https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/api